# When to create multiple pages instead of combining pages into a single page with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When should one create multiple pages for the display of content instead or creating one centralized page which fetches the data to display via PHP and MySQL?

---

My specific case is this: I have a math website which features calculators for various simple purposes such as simplifying radicals, solving for exponents, etc. Currently, each calculator has its own page (so there is `simplifying_radicals.php` and `solving_for_exponents.php`), resulting in multiple pages for the calculators.

I'm wondering whether I should condense all those pages into a single page which fetches content from a database. For example, if a user visited `calculators.php?calculator=simplifying_radicals`, the PHP page would fetch all the data from the simplifying_radicals row to display appropriately.

The database would contain a link to each calculator's script (it is calculated via Javascript), a medium-length description of the process, and practice problems for the user to try on their own. Each calculator has a similar format, but I'm worried that condensing the calculators into a single page would decrease flexibility and be slower because the server would have to fetch the content from the database.

---

So, basically, I'm interested in the following:

1. The original question which is in the title.
2. How those guidelines would apply to my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this

```
<?php

// Your header stuff

switch($_GET['calculator']) {

  case 'simplifying_radicals':
    require_once 'simplifying_radicals.php';
    break;

  ...etc

}

// Your footer stuff

?>
```

That way all code that's shared between your calculators would only have to be written in the header and footer region and the calculator files would only contain what's specific to them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you have a huge amount of code in each different page, so keep them separated. By the way you make them easier to read, extend, maintain and debug.

If you have just a few lines in each page, merge them in a single file. Now that's a better way for keeping them readable and so on.

If you have a high load on each page, or you have lots of process, or for example your MySQL tables contains hundred of thousands of records, then you may split them again for performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use a switch statement like @Eric's answer, but now use a class:

```
// foo.php
class FooController extends PageController
{
  public function someAction()
  {
  }

  public function someOtherAction()
  {
  }
}

new FooController()->run();
```

If you go to `/foo/some` it will execute `someAction()`, a d `/foo/some-other` executes `someOtherAction()`.

A lot of the messy code (such as creating nav/footer HTML, and deciding which "action" to run) happens in the parent PageController class).

Deciding when how many pages to put in each class is a matter of personal taste and organization. Find the right balance between having a many files with almost no code and a few massive files with so much code you can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons of using separate files is to avoid code repetition.
Anther reason is that the software is easier to maintain and scale when functionality is separated in different files and properly included in the main project. Simply using "include" to bring a file in the main php file won't do it, but using filters that other pages can use to connect in different parts of the main php file is a big plus(for example you can check the wordpress filters)
In your case:
you have a page where you have all your calculators that users can choose from, but what if you want to place the most simple calculator in a sidebar, if you have the calculator in a different file you just include that one in the sidebar(it also depands on how you insert your sidebar)